# Como pasarle parámetros a un handler de input file

Tags: javascript, fileupload

Tengo un input html

```
<input type="file" @change="handleImg" accept="image/*">
```

Y la función `handleImg`

```
handleImg(e){
  const img = e.target.files[0]
  ...
},
```

> No entiendo como la función `handleImg`, sin pasarle ningún parámetro al llamarla entiende que el elemento con la imágen es lo que se llama `e` en la definición de la función.

**Yo quisiera pasarle un segundo parámetro**, intenté hacer la llamada a la función con

```
handleImg($el, item) o con

handleImg(_, item) 


handleImg($event, item) o con // <- Esta era la respuesta, evidentemente lo probé mal
```

Y siempre recibo error. Alguna sugerencia de cómo hacer para pasar varios parámetros? Muchas gracias

Comment: y que sería item?

Comment: @LuisS.Romero un id que me indica dónde guardar la imágen. Tengo un boton que al clickearlo agrega un input para que pueda subir la imagen. Tambien hay botones para crear otras cosas y se pueden crear varias imagenes. Por eso con un id se me ocurrio que puedo guardarla como corresponde.

Comment: Te acepté la respuesta, evidentemente no escribí bien $event porque creí haberlo intentado. Muchas gracias, además me sirvió la explicación.

Comment: Me alegra mucho haber podido aclarar un poco más, gracias por la calificación, quedo a las órdenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La **e** se refiere al evento, cuando se dispara (change en este caso, es decir cuando hay un cambio) este evento devuelve un objeto que por defecto es el primer parámetro de la función, este se puede capturar con cualquier nombre, los más comunes son **e**, **ev** y **event**, dentro del **objeto event** existe un **target** que hace referencia al elemento sobre el que se escucha el evento, en este caso tu input. Entonces dentro de **event.target** o **e.target** en tu caso tienes disponible lo referente al input, por lo que en **e.target.files** tienes lo que has subido.

Por el @change deduzco que estás utilizando Vue, para pasar el evento y un segundo parámetro deberías usar una sintaxis como la siguiente:

```
<input type="file" @change="handleImg($event, anotherParam)">
```

Donde seguirías recibiendo como primer parámetro el evento y en el segundo parámetro el otro argumento que desees enviar, ejemplo item.id.